# MS Access pass-through Select query to SQL Server with a parameter

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I'm trying to use a pass-through query to return records from SQL Server to MS Access that have a specific value in the column `AssignedAgent`. The assigned agent changes depending on who has logged in, the assigned agent ID is stored in a main menu screen that is always open.

The SQL pass-through query below works perfectly, but instead of "2" it needs to point to `[forms]![mainmenuf]!UserIDtxt]` this is how I pointed to the field in the main menu when whole table was linked.

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.allrecordst 
WHERE assignedagent = 2
```

Could someone provide the correct syntax for SQL Server to find the assigned agent on the main menu form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so at logon time, you want to execute this code:

```
 dim strSQL    as string
 strSQL = "SELECT * FROM dbo.allrecordst WHERE assignedagent = " & _
    [forms]![mainmenuf]!UserIDtxt]
 CurrentDb.querydefs("myPTQuery").SQL = strSQL
```

After above runs, then you can launch a form or report based on above query. And the above query can also be opened to a VBA recordset.